# Apply a required field validator when Listview Item Value = x

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview that users use to enter some data. I have applied some required fields validators using a ValidationGroup that triggers on the Insert button.

However, I now need a different validation rule to trigger if a particular value is added to the listview via a drop down list in the template field.

I can do this using a GridView but....the GridView doesn't support Insert so I am stumped.

Can anyone please help??

Comment: GridViews do support insert. Generally, if you need a validator in a GridView, you can add one into a `template field`. Search for converting a bound field to a template field.

Comment: Thanks Wazz. Yes I got that now!